# HTTP requests taking longer when threaded | Python 3.6

Tags: multithreading, http, python-requests, request

I'm trying to // 2 or more API calls to different servers at the exact same time.

Those calls if made in sequence take 0.5 seconds (on average), but whenever I thread them they take something like 0.7 when // 2 calls, 1.2 when using 4 calls etc.

0.7 is still better than 0.5 x 2 and 1.2 is still better than 0.5 x 4 seconds. However I don't understand why when // two calls it doesn't take 0.5 on average.

Here is the code I use (the function actually call methods of different classes, could the delay come from that when threading ?)

```
import multiprocessing.dummy

pool = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool()

def function(data):
    timer = time()
    new_data = *api_call*
    print(time() - timer)
    return new_data

# Option 1:
data = pool.map(book, [data1, data2])

# Option 2:
data = function(data1)
data += function(data2)
```

I would be awesome if I found a way to get those responses as fast as when calling alone, speed is very important in my case, and if I can make 4-6 API calls (on different servers) at the same time would be really great.

Comment: Also experiencing this behavior. Have you figured out why this is happening? Or any fix? Thanks